# unity public variable not showing with gameObject.find

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

I have a script here called EnemyHealth and a script called DatabaseManager. in the DatabaseManager script I am trying to reference a newly created public int deathCount variable from the EnenmyHealth script, but that public variable isn't showing for me while all others are, here is the code

EnemyHealth

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int startingHealth = 100;            // The amount of health the enemy starts the game with.
        public bool isDead;                                // Whether the enemy is dead.
        public int deathCount;
        public int currentHealth;                   // The current health the enemy has.
        public float sinkSpeed = 2.5f;              // The speed at which the enemy sinks through the floor when dead.
        public int scoreValue = 10;                 // The amount added to the player's score when the enemy dies.
        public AudioClip deathClip;                 // The sound to play when the enemy dies.
```

DatabaseManager

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class DatabaseManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        int x = GameObject.Find("ZomBear").GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().deathCount;
    }
```

it just doesn't seem to find this one variable whilst all the other public ones are visible

Comment: What is the actual issue? Do you get a runtime error or you get a value that you do not expect?

Comment: hello, it is not letting me reference the deathCount variable saying that EnemyHealth does not contain a definition for deathCount, when it is infact declared but i just cant reference it

Comment: its not showing the red line under deathCount in the code because its just pasted

Comment: OK, seems that the issue is due to the namespace that's defined for EnemyHealth. I tried to give an answer, please let me know if it helps you out.

Comment: Did you save all the files?

Comment: go into your ide and hit save all. there is nothing wrong with that variable, sometimes i do this where i edit two scripts, and save one, then i have to go back and save the other. worth a shot.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, Andreas answer fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `EnemyHealth` is inside the `CompleteProject` namespace: you should add

```
using CompleteProject
```

at the top of `DatabaseManager` script, in order to have visibility of that namespace.

Comment: Or put the namespace in front of the class name: `int x = GameObject.Find("ZomBear").GetComponent<CompleteProject.EnemyHealth>().deathCount;`. The title of this question is misleading. Use comes from `GetComponent` not `GameObject.Find`.

Comment: @Programmer: thank you for your comment: absolutely agree on both the points.

Comment: thank you for your answer Andrea, it worked, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE hit save all. ensure that when you edit multiple scripts, you save the nw version of all scripts involved. sounds simple, but i have done this hundreds of times, and it usually only takes a sec to realize it.